# Could not find method compile()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, zxing

I want to add a lib in android studio but it is not working.
Here is a screenshot

[image]

I also tried to add a dependency in the gradle.build but that also does not work. Maybe it is because I am behind a proxy ?

[image]

Comment: Did you read `NOTE`, that located at line 14?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **are using the wrong** `build.gradle` file.

You can't use `compile` in the top-level file.
Use the `module/build.gradle`.

`<PROJECT_ROOT>\app\build.gradle` is specific **for app module**.

`<PROJECT_ROOT>\build.gradle` is a **"Top-level build file"** where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

Also you should include the libraries in the `dependencies` block, not inside the `buildscript` block.

Top level file example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

In the `app\build.gradle` you define only the properties for the module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion ...
    buildToolsVersion ...
}

dependencies {
    //..... HERE !
}
```